# How to use SQL(Max) function

Tags: sql-server, function, max

I have 2 tables

`Table 1`:

```
id     name      adress 
1      John      New York
2      Jane      London`
```

... and so on

`Table 2`:

```
id    fila      date
1     43        01/01/2010
1     39        10/01/2011
1     55        23/12/2012
2     10        01/01/2008
2     15        02/02/2010`
```

.... and so on

I want to get data like this

```
id  fila   name     adress       date
-----------------------------------------
1   55     John    New York    23/12/2012
2   15     Jane    London      02/02/2010
```

..... and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `max(fila)` or `max(date)`? Both will work for the sample given, but I'd like to know to be sure.

Comment: I need max(fila) from each id from table2 and combine with data from table1, Thanks

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. You could try my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
 (select id, max(fila) maxfila
  from table2
  group by id)
 select t1.id, t1.name, t1.address, t2.fila, t2.date
 from table1 t1 
 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 inner join cte c on t1.id = c.id
 where t2.fila = c.maxfila
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a sql view from this solution?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/viewwithcte/

Answer (score 1):

ok. what you are really looking for is "What is the latest date in table2 for each of my rows in Table1". So to answer the question:

```
select *
From Table1
inner join (
    select id, max(fila) as maxfila
    from Table2
    group by id
) as maxdates
on Table1.id = maxdates.id
inner join Table2 on Table2.id = maxdates.id AND Table2.fila = maxdates.maxfila
```

Comment: You'll need one more join to get the `fila` value.

Comment: I need to obtain the max(fila) from each id from table 2, and combine the result with data from table1: name, address):

Comment: @atty try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select t1.id, t1.name, t1.address, t2.maxfila
 from table1 t1 
  left outer join 
  (select id, max(fila) maxfila
  from table2
  group by id) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.name t1.address, max(t2.fila), 
(select top 1 date from table2 order by fila desc where table2.id = t1.id)
 from table1 t1 inner join 
 table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: doesn't work.I nedd max(fila) from each id in table2 combine with data on table 1